# Inefficient code inside of getter?

Tags: c#, properties

I have two lists of the same type and I want to be able view a list of both lists:

```
    public List<Page> HeaderPages;
    public List<Page> SurveyPages;

    public IReadOnlyList<Page> AllPages 
    { 
        get 
        {
            List<Page> allPages = new List<Page>();
            allPages.AddRange(this.HeaderPages);
            allPages.AddRange(this.SurveyPages);
            return allPages;
        } 
    }
```

I think it is very inefficient to keep creating a new list object each time I want to get `AllPages`, so I thought I could store a private `allPages` list.  But then I thought if I am in the class, I would have to remember to use the public `AllPages` rather than the private `allPages` - which may not be up-to-date.

Any elegant solutions?

Comment: Can you post an example of some code which demonstrates the problem? You're asking us to review a hypothetical class which contains a private allPages list, and a hypothetical method which finds it difficult to remember whether to reference allPages or AllPages ... but it's difficult to understand hypothetical (non-existent) code.

Comment: I don't know C# enough to write an answer, but what if everytime the get was called you saved the result in an instance variable and set something like "changed = false" alse as an instance variable. Whenever get is called, if changed is false just return your cached list. Then anything in the class that changed the other two lists sets changed to true.

Comment: Do you actually need to optimise this? How often do you call the getter?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have control over the design of the Page class, I would add a "bool IsHeader" property to it and keep one public list of all Page objects and add every Page object to that list. Instead of keeping several other lists that sort your Page objects, you can then perform searches on that master list instead for Page objects with certain properties, preferably with LINQ statements.

Comment: I think this is a really nice advice.

Comment: Even if he has control over `Page` class, how do you know both `HeaderPages` and `SurveyPages` are not non-empty?

Comment: I would do it completely without HeaderPages and SurveyPages, that's the whole point of my answer.

Comment: I agree with this because it's a far more elegant solution, *however* if the OP is worried about the overhead of instantiating a single list, then doing O(n) operations on all data accesses might not be their favourite. They'd be wrong, of course, as n is almost certainly trivial.

Comment: I do have control of the `Page` class. In the end I decided this method was best suited to my project.

Comment: Why not use an `enum` instead of `bool`?  This will allow easier modification in the future if more page types pop up?

Answer (score 16):

If you want to keep the two lists (otherwise check **Hackworth**'s answer), the best solution would be to use LINQ extensions

```
public IEnumerable<Page> AllPages 
{ 
    get 
    {
        return HeaderPages.Concat(SurveyPages);
    } 
}
```

This way you do not create any unnecessary collections. It forces you to use `IEnumerable<Page>` though, but in my opinion it is a good thing.

Comment: +1 The difference between IReadOnlyList and IEnumerable is (only) that IReadOnlyList also supports Count and Index properties.

Comment: Thanks, I really like this very clean solution and and will definitely try it out on other projects.

Answer (score 5):

As you said, keep another List which will contains all the elements and when you add an element inside one of the two update the internal List ... you could make List private and make helper method which update the main list and the internal List.

With your code anyway you will create a List every item it's called and I think it could lead to bugs if you keep the reference sonewhere and you except it's updated (it's isn't,  will keep values of when is created) with the latest pages.

Another way is to keep your approch but create the List only once and return it. Then you should find a way to let know to the class if one of the List changed, if changed update the list (clear and readd to avoid a new instance)

I could add code example if you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can use lazy initialization to achieve the same:

```
private Lazy<List<Page>> _lazyPageList = new Lazy<List<Page>>(GetPageList);

public IReadOnlyList<Page> AllPages
{
    get
    {
        return lazyPageList.Value;
    }
}

private List<Page >GetPageList(){
    List<Page> allPages = new List<Page>();
    allPages.AddRange(this.HeaderPages);
    allPages.AddRange(this.SurveyPages);
    return allPages;
}
```

Comment: And what good will it do? You will still have to update `AllPages` somehow when other collections change.

Comment: What I understand from the original question the lists do not change. The idea is to avoid creating a new list everytime **AllPages** property is accessed. @chazjn doesn't want to create a member variable to store the result. Lazy class is best suited for this.

Comment: from question: "I could store a private 'allPages' list, but then I thought if I am in the class I would have to remember to use the public 'AllPages' rather than the private 'allPages' - *which may not be up-to-date*." Introducing `Lazy` property does not solve this issue, it only adds extra complexity to the code. (you still create an extra field `_lazyPageList`)

Comment: I agree with you that new changes will not be updated with lazy approach. However whether you use the linq extension or the code in the original post a new list will be created every time the property is accessed. A better approach would be to store the result temporarilty to a variable and update it only if the either of the list has changed

Comment: linq does not create new list. It creates new enumeration logic over existing collection(-s). To create a new list you'd have to call `ToList()` method.

Answer (score 3):

Have you profiled your code and determined that this call is problem? If not, do that before optimising anything.

There is a general solution to problems like this, which is to use a `dirty` flag to track whether the return value is valid. To do this you will want to wrap all the cases when the header and survey pages can be modified in a manner that breaks the allpages list and have these calls set the `dirty` flag. Then replace your getter with something like this:

```
private List<page> allPages;
private boolean dirty;

public IReadOnlyList<Page> AllPages 
{ 
    get 
    {
        if (dirty)
        {
           allPages = new List<Page>();
           allPages.AddRange(this.HeaderPages);
           allPages.AddRange(this.SurveyPages);
        }
        return allPages;
    } 
}
```

Unfortunately `dirty` flags can be error prone so tread with care.

Comment: There's a bug in the sample code: allPages names a local variable and a member. Also, if dirty would you prefer `allPages = new List<Page>();` or `allPages.Clear();`?

Comment: @ChrisW I would say just create a new list and let the old one get collected.  If you try to do the Clear, you need to check to see if the allPages is initialized first.

Comment: @ChrisW: Thanks, I've fixed that bug. I don't know which is more efficient in C#, you'd have to time it.

Answer (score 1):

Two alternatives to [Hackworth's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45391/34757) if you don't have control of the Page class:

- Either, create two subclasses HeaderPage and SurveyPage, bother/either of which you can store in the  `List<Page> AllPages`
- Or, add a `Dictionary<Page,bool>` in which to remember the type of page (the 'type of page' is shown here as a `bool`, but could be an `enum`) for each page in your single `List<Page> AllPages`

Access to that dictionary could be defined as an extention method:

```
static class PageExtensions
{
    // Or this could be a non-static member of your container class and passed
    // as a parameter into the GetPageType and SetPageType extension methods.
    static Dictionary<Page, bool> dictionary = new Dictionary<Page, bool>();

    public static bool? GetPageType(this Page page)
    {
        bool rc;
        return (dictionary.TryGetValue(page, out rc)) ? rc : null;
    }
    public static void SetPageType(this Page page, bool type)
    {
        dictionary[page] = type;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bool means nothing in this context.  I would change it to an `enum` that names the page type.

Comment: I did say, "could be an enum" in the answer. Alternatively rename the associated extensions methods, e.g. to SetIsHeader instead of SetPageType.

Answer (score 0):

What are people going to want to do with `AllPages`, and are they going to have any expectations about how it should behave if the underlying data changes?

If the intention is that code which reads `AllPages` isn't going to use it after the next time anything changes, you could have each instance of your self create (or lazily create) an instance of `AllPageWrapper`, which holds a reference to its creator along with a "change count" and possibly the number of items in `HeaderPages`.  Methods and properties of `AllPageWrapper` would ensure the wrapped object had not been modified, and would then use that wrapped object as a source of data.  The indexed getter might look something like:

```
public Page this(int index)
{ get
  {
    if (changeCount != parent.changeCount)
      throw InvalidOPerationException(...);
    if (index > headerCount)
      return parent.SurveyPages(index-headerCount);
    else
      return parent.HeaderPages(index);
  }
}
```

Such an approach would allow the `AllPages` property to simply return a wrapper object, without having to do any real "work".  Code which needs a detached copy of the list could use use `thing.AllPages.ToList()`, but code which will need it only briefly need not bother.